# Why does win32con.WM_KEYUP and win32con.WM_KEYDOWN do the same thing?

Tags: python, winapi, automation, win32gui

I am trying to send keystrokes to a specific window on my computer but win32con.WM_KEYDOWN and win32con.WM_KEYUP both hold down the key for some reason. I need to hold it down for a period of time and then release the key.

I have tried:

```
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api

hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "example app")
win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, 0x57, 0)
```

which holds the W key down.

And I have tried

```
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api

hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "example app")
win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYUP, 0x57, 0)
```

Which also holds the W key down despite having `win32con.WM_KEYUP` in the code instead of `win32con.WM_KEYDOWN`.